# "Exception: Gradle build failed" only for flutter project in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

My Flutter project works fine, I can build it as Android app with VisualStudio Code. With AndroidStudio I am able to build the Android app if I open only the android folder and build the Android app as android project.
But if I open the whole Flutter project in AndroidStudio and try to build it for Android (iOS works fine) I get this error:
Exception: Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under .../build, but the tool couldn't find it.
Seems like an IDE bug, is there anyone with a solution for me?

Android Studio version : Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 (Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386, built on January 11, 2023)

Update:
app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    flavorDimensions "distribute"
    productFlavors {
        appCenter {
            dimension "distribute"
        }

        googlePlay {
            dimension "distribute"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "myId"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 3
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Electric Eel is very buggy and unstable at the moment. Please downgrade to Dolphin or lower

Comment: Same exception with Android Studio Chipmunk

Comment: Does it work when you use `flutter run` from console? It looks like you've something messed with flavors or signing config.

Comment: If I use the flutter run command, the exception also shows up.

Comment: So, that's not Android Studio problem. Show your app build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no default flavor defined, so you need to specify flavor to build. From command line:

`flutter run --flavor appCenter` (or googlePlay)

In Android Studio, go to Run->Edit configurations and set flavor to build (in your case `appCenter` or `googlePlay`. You can also add new configuration to be able to swith between them to build different flavor.